# Randomly run two SKActions at same time for two separate SKSpriteNodes

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

Title says it all. I've got two SKSpriteNodes [ leftTrap, rightTrap] with two separate SKActions [ rotateSequenceLeft, rotateSequence] that need to run at the same time but need to do it randomly.

### SKSpriteNodes with attached SKActions

Need to run these two in parallel at same random intervals.

```
   leftTrap.run(SKAction.repeatForever(rotateSequenceLeft))
   rightTrap.run(SKAction.repeatForever(rotateSequence))
```

### What I have tried

I have tried to group the leftTrap node and action rotateSequenceLeft with a wait duration range action. But it seems that the created group never even runs the wait duration action.

```
        let randomPivotInterval = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0, withRange: 5.0)


        let leftGroup = SKAction.group([rotateSequenceLeft, randomPivotInterval])

        let rightGroup = SKAction.group([rotateSequence, randomPivotInterval])



   leftTrap.run(SKAction.repeatForever(leftGroup))
   rightTrap.run(SKAction.repeatForever(rightGroup))
```

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want.  Each sprite constantly rotating at a different but fixed rate? Each sprite constantly rotating at a constantly varying rate?  Each sprite rotating at some fixed rate but then with a random pause between rotations? One or the other sprite rotating, but a random choice between them and perhaps switching from one to the other at random? Is there supposed to be some correlation between the sprites, i.e., why have you posed the question with two sprites instead of just one?

Comment: rotateSequenceLeft rotates the angle of the sprite 90 degrees then puts it back. rotateSequence does the same but with the right sprite.

So together they both rotate, opening up a space for a character to fall into. So they need to do so at the same time just need to do it randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both flippers need to be in sync at all times, just apply the action to the left flipper, and do this for the right:

```
func didEvaluateActions(){
    rightTrap.angle = -leftTrap.angle
}
```

This will ensure both flippers are always at the opposite angle

Comment: Depending on how the geometry is set up, the angles might need to be computed differently. E.g., if both sprites have the same texture with initial rotations 0 and .pi, then it's probably something like right.zRotation = .pi - left.zRotation

Comment: There is no real clarity as to what is going on, otherwise I would provide a better answer.  Just going off of what is given.

Comment: Of course, just pointing out to the OP that it requires a little thought and they shouldn't assume the approach doesn't work if it doesn't behave like they expect at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var leftTrap: SKSpriteNode! // TODO: populate this
    var rightTrap: SKSpriteNode! // TODO: populate this

    func start() {
        let rotateTraps = SKAction.run { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.rotate(trap: self.leftTrap, clockwise: .random())
            self.rotate(trap: self.rightTrap, clockwise: .random())
        }

        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([rotateTraps, wait])
        run(.repeatForever(sequence))

    }

    private func rotate(trap: SKSpriteNode, clockwise: Bool) {
        // TODO: put rotation code here
    }

}
```

### How does it work?

The `start()` method creates a `rotateTraps` action which, each time it is executed, call self?.rotate on the left trap passing a random bool for the clockwise param and then does the same for the right trap.

Then the `rotateTraps` action is wrapped into a sequence and repeated forever every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you don't want to add a post-evaluate phase like in Knight0fDragon's answer, then you can probably do something like this:

```swift
func operateTrap() {
  run(.wait(forDuration: .random(in: 1.0 ... 6.0)) { // On completion...
    // I assume both sequences take the same time.
    leftTrap.run(rotateSequenceLeft)
    rightTrap.run(rotateSequenceRight) { self.operateTrap() }
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this,  the completion used to be bugged where it would restart the previous action.  I would recommend using a sequence instead of the completion block just to be safe.

Comment: Maybe. I haven't personally had any issues, but I've only been doing iOS development and using SpriteKit for about 6 months.

Comment: Yeah it is one if the things I have encountered when adding actions to already completed runs,  it could be fixed by now, but apple has a tendency of reintroducing bugs.